# Android get GPS coords in Async method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, gps

i have MainActivty and MyLocationListener classes.

MyLocationListener extends AsyncTask implements LocationListener..

Here is code of the Location Listener Class:

private class MyLocationListener extends AsyncTask implements LocationListener {

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // convert coords from double to string
            String lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            String lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

            Log.i(AppHelper.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "lat " + lat);
            Log.i(AppHelper.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "lon " + lon);

            // save actual position into shared preferences storage
            _appPrefs = new AppPreferences(activityContext);
            _appPrefs.saveSomeString("lat", lat);
            _appPrefs.saveSomeString("lon", lon);

            getAddressByCoords(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude());
            setPositionToView(activityContext, mView);
    }

    /**
     * Method get string representation of the place in given coords
     * 
     * @param lat
     *            double
     * @param lon
     *            double
     * @return List <Address>
     * @throws Exception
     */

    public List<Address> getAddressByCoords(double lat, double lon) {

        Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(activityContext);
        try {
            addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Log.d("APP",
                        "LOCATION " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                Log.d("APP",
                        "LOCATION " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1));
                Log.d("APP",
                        "LOCATION " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                provider + "'s status changed to " + status + "!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider " + provider + " enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider " + provider + " disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {
            // Define the criteria how to select the location provider
            criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE); // default
            criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

            // get the best provider depending on the criteria
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

            // the last known location of this provider
            Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            // request single update
            this.onLocationChanged(location);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(AppHelper.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE,
                    "doInBackground method cannot be processed", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If i'm trying to get GPS coords using the:

```
// Get the location manager
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                mView = view;
                boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // get values from user settings
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            Boolean prefferNativeGPs = sharedPrefs.getBoolean(
                    "prefNativeGps", false);

            Log.i("APP", "GPS enabled " + isGPSEnabled); // false
            Log.i("APP", "NETWORK enabled " + isNetworkEnabled); // true
            Log.i("APP", "USE native " + prefferNativeGPs); // true

            // blink textview
            TextView stateTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
            stateTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            startBlinkText();
    Log.i("APP", "GPS POSITION USING GPS_PROVIDER");
    Toast.makeText(this,R.string.parking_car_using_gps_it_can_take_more_time,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // calling doInBackground
    new MyLocationListener().execute("");
```

I got following exception in doInBackground:

*cannot create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare*

I would like to ask, how to modify my code to do processing correctly?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Create the handler in the AsyncTask's constructor.  You must make it on a thread with an active message loop, like the UI thread.

Comment: Could You please post some code example for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the location is already an async operation...

All you need to do is to call it on the UI thread, and expect new results soon afterwards (depends on many things).

That's why it has a listener. Otherwise it would just return you a response while blocking you...